# Application freezing when loosing focus

Tags: c++, qt, focus, freeze

I've done an application doing complex calculations (it lasts several minutes or much more) and I've noticed that if the app looses the focus, it freezes. If I keep the focus on it, it's working well. 
It's just a UI with one button that I've done with qt designer. There are 2 progressBars who stops when the QMainWindow looses the focus.
Have you ever heard about this problem? Maybe it comes from one of the QMainWindow property?
Thank you for your help

EDIT: Even if UI freezes, calculation is still running. But it's boring for the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're doing the calculation on the main (GUI) thread. Create a separate, worker object for processing the calculations and move it to a new thread.

There's a great example of how to do this [here](https://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/).

Comment: Yes, this is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `QCoreApplication::processEvents()` during your computations, to prevent freezing. Also you can use `QThread` as a working thread, but it's a more complex solution.

Comment: Should I add this line in my calculation function? Or somewhere else? Cause using it directly in my function doesn't work on freezes.

Comment: It would have to be in any loop that is holding up your work. Better to use a seperate thread for the work.